Can't install tensorflow in Anaconda
So I am running the latest Anaconda, and I am trying to run tensorflow but my install gets stuck here
info     libmamba Adding job: conda-forge/win-64::zlib==1.2.13=h2466b09_6

but when I check my anaconda environment, it says I have zlib 1.2.13 installed
I left it run for hours and it did not move at all.
I am working on Windows 10, latest Anaconda release
Any ideas?

Hi @Alejandro Diaz, Could you please refer to this Tensorflow install official doc to install Tensorflow using Anaconda on your WinOS and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.
